# How to Angular form data added to model array?

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Senderv3 } from 'app/models/codec/senderv3';
import { CustomerInfoService } from '../../../services/customer-info.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-senderv3',
  templateUrl: './senderv3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./senderv3.component.scss']
})
export class Senderv3Component implements OnInit {

  VirtualMsisdn = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  OperatorVariantId = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  SmsHeader = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  ServiceCode = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  form: FormGroup;

  senders: Senderv3[] = [ { VirtualMsisdn: this.VirtualMsisdn.value, OperatorVariantId: this.OperatorVariantId.value, 
    SmsHeader: this.SmsHeader.value, ServiceCode: this.ServiceCode.value } ] as Senderv3[];

  constructor(private customerInfoService: CustomerInfoService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      VirtualMsisdn: this.VirtualMsisdn,
      OperatorVariantId: this.OperatorVariantId,
      SmsHeader: this.SmsHeader,
      ServiceCode: this.ServiceCode,
    });
  }

  insertSenderv3() {
    this.customerInfoService.insertSendersv3(this.senders).subscribe();  
  }


}
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="insertSenderv3()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

Why parameter object insertSendersv3(this.senders) are empty? (OperatorVariantId:""
ServiceCode:""
SmsHeader:""
VirtualMsisdn:"")

see screenshots:

[picture 1](https://ibb.co/d9DSaV) 
[picture 2](https://ibb.co/nRow2A)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you want the json value of the form ?

Comment: Yes, I want json value of the form.

Comment: you can get the value of form using ``this.form.value``

Comment: I tried, but how do I bind class Senderv3?

Comment: just do a ``this.senders.push(this.form.value)``

Comment: push worked thank you very much

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `formBuilder` , you don't have to create a control like : `new FormControl('',Validators.required)`

Since its a simple form , i would create the form something like this :

```
  form: FormGroup;

  senders: Senderv3[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      VirtualMsisdn: ['' ,  Validators.required],
      OperatorVariantId: ['' ,  Validators.required],
      SmsHeader: ['' ,  Validators.required],
      ServiceCode: ['' ,  Validators.required],
    });
  }

  insertSenderv3() {
    this.senders.push(this.form.value);
    console.log(this.senders)
  }
```

Now if you end up clicking the button , the `this.form.value` will have your value which will be of type `Senderv3` .

I have created an example on stackBlitz . You can check this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxfynp